# .NET 6 OAuth2 renew token

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

On a .NET 6 Web App I use OAuth2 with an external provider for authentication. The access token is valid for two hours, an renew token is available as well. I want to use the access token from the OAuth provider to get more data from the providers API, but the access_token is not renewed after it's expired.

I'm looking for a way to renew the access token with the refresh token when it's about to expire.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

const string AuthSchemeName = "MyOauth2";
const string CookieSchemeName = "MyCookie";

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
{
    opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieSchemeName;
    opts.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieSchemeName;
    opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = AuthSchemeName;
})
.AddCookie(CookieSchemeName)
.AddOAuth(AuthSchemeName, opts =>
{
    opts.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://git.example.de/oauth/authorize";
    opts.TokenEndpoint = "https://git.example.de/oauth/token";
    opts.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://git.example.de/oauth/userinfo";
    opts.CallbackPath = new PathString("/authorization-code/callback");
    opts.ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    opts.ClientSecret = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

    opts.Scope.Add("openid");
    opts.Scope.Add("profile");
    opts.Scope.Add("email");
    opts.Scope.Add("read_user");
    opts.Scope.Add("read_api");

    opts.SaveTokens = true;

    opts.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
    opts.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "nickname");
    opts.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
    opts.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, "groups");

    opts.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            // Get user info from the userinfo endpoint and use it to populate user claims
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var user = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            context.RunClaimActions(user.RootElement);

            context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
        }
    };
});
```

I'm getting the access token like this in Controllers:

```cs
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("MyOauth2", "access_token");
```

Comment: the `external provider` doesn't provide you a method to refresh the access token?

Comment: It does but I am looking for an function in .NET 6 to automate the renewal of the token. I would expect that such a feature exists in a open id implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this, to call the token endpoint and then to rewrite cookies. You can write code similar to this, when you get a 401 response from an API, and adapt the code based on your own preferences:

```cs
private async Task<JsonNode> RefreshTokens(HttpContext context)
{
    var tokenEndpoint = this.configuration.GetValue<string>("OpenIdConnect:TokenEndpoint");
            
    var clientId = this.configuration.GetValue<string>("OpenIdConnect:ClientId");
    var clientSecret = this.configuration.GetValue<string>("OpenIdConnect:ClientSecret");
    var refreshToken = await context.GetTokenAsync(REFRESH_TOKEN);

    var requestData = new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", REFRESH_TOKEN),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken),
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
    
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json");
                
        var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData));
                
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonNode.Parse(json).AsObject();
    }
}

private async Task RewriteCookies(JsonNode tokens, HttpContext context)
{   
    var accessToken = tokens[ACCESS_TOKEN]?.ToString();
    var refreshToken = tokens[REFRESH_TOKEN]?.ToString();
    var idToken = tokens[ID_TOKEN]?.ToString();

    var newTokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
    newTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken{ Name = ACCESS_TOKEN, Value = accessToken });

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(refreshToken))
    {
        refreshToken = await context.GetTokenAsync(REFRESH_TOKEN);
    }
    newTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken{ Name = REFRESH_TOKEN, Value = refreshToken });

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(idToken))
    {
        idToken = await context.GetTokenAsync(ID_TOKEN);
    }
    newTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken{ Name = ID_TOKEN, Value = idToken });

    var properties = context.Features.Get<IAuthenticateResultFeature>().AuthenticateResult.Properties;
            
    properties.StoreTokens(newTokens);
    await context.SignInAsync(context.User, properties);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I found `Duende.AccessTokenManagement` in the meantime and it does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet package `Duende.AccessTokenManagement` did the trick: https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Duende.AccessTokenManagement

After switching to `AddOpenIdConnect` it is just adding `builder.Services.AddAccessTokenManagement();` to the Startup and add a http client to dependency injection:

```
builder.Services.AddUserAccessTokenHttpClient("oidprovider", configureClient: client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com");
})
.AddUserAccessTokenHandler();
```

In a controller the `IHttpClientFactory` can be used to get an instance of this HttpClient.